# Extract block of numerical data using regec in python

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I am trying to parse a file that presents some sections of numerical data. The goal is to extract each block of data for further parsing. The fact is that these sections span multiple lines (ended by \n), possibly with spaces at the beginning and the last line of the section presents the keyword END :

```
1 2 3 4
 2 5 6 7
3 8 9 10
*END


1 11  12 13
2 14 15 16
3 17 18 19
*END
```

What I want to extract with regex is the list of strings:

```
['1 2 3 4\n 2 5 6 7\n3 8 9 10',
 '1 11  12 13\n2 14 15 16\n3 17 18 19']
```

I do :

```
import re
ifile = open('file.dat', 'r')
data = ifile.read()
```

Then the regex pattern I built for a line is :

```
line = r'^(\s*\d+(?:\s+\d+){3}\s*)$'
pattern = re.compile(line, re.MULTILINE)
pattern.findall(data)
```

Then I get:

```
['1 2 3 4',
 ' 2 5 6 7',
 '3 8 9 10',
 '\n\n1 11  12 13',
 '2 14 15 16',
 '3 17 18 19']
```

A first question would be why the '\n' are retained in the fourth string ?

The way I would do to extract the two sections is:

```
section = r'(?:(' + line + ')*)\*END'
pattern = re.compile(section, re.MULTILINE)
pattern.findall(data)
```

But I can't manage to make it work. Maybe something I don't understand with MULTILINE flag ?

---

***Edit :***

I would like to specify the structure of a line (1 integer followed by 3 other integers) inside my regex. The solution of vks works but I would like to be a bit more specific. I tried the following :

for a line :

```
^\s*\d+(?:\s+\d+){4}\s*$
```

It works well (http://regex101.com/r/qZ6sE3/6)

For a section :

```
((?:^\s*\d+(?:\s+\d+){4}\s*$)*)(?=\s*\*END)
```

The idea here is to duplicate the line to form a multiline block and matching it only if it is followed by a line with *END.

http://regex101.com/r/qZ6sE3/7

However, the result is not that expected. It matches the last line but also some void strings... Any help in understanding ?

Regards,
François.

Comment: is `*END` really exists?

Comment: Yes it does. This is not the best way to delimit data but that was not my choice...

Comment: I have edited my post as I need more help...

Comment: could you provide an expected output? So that we could figure out the problem

Answer (score 1):

To answer to your question why the newline characters where present before the character `1` is because there where two empty lines before it.

As the data block is split based on '*END' text we can use it as delimiter and divide the file content into list. And then we can traverse the list and the use regex to process the data and collect the numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

data = open('file').read().split('*END')

items = []

for x in data:
    items.append(re.findall('(\d+)\s+', x))

print(items)
```

Output

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '5', '6', '7', '3', '8', '9', '10'], 
['1', '11', '12', '13', '2', '14', '15', '16', '3', '17', '18', '19'], []]
```

Here the list `items` has the contents of each block within a separate list.

Answer (score 0):

> A first question would be why the '\n' are retained in the fourth string ?

Because they are matched by the first `\s*`.

In general, I would suggest to "parse" the file line by line, skipping empty lines and regex-parsing non-empty lines. Something like

```
data = []
block = []
for line in ifile.readlines():
  if not line.strip():
    continue
  elif line.startswith("*END"):
    data.append(block)
    block = []
  elif:
    m = re.match(r"(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)", line)
    block.append(m.groups())
```

Comment: Ok, I did not know that \s also match \n. Is there a way to match only spaces, not newline characters ?

Comment: I would like to avoid parsing the file line by line because other kind of data could appear in the file, not being a data section as described. The goal for me is to detect and extract sections as described.

Comment: Ok for the literal space, but what if I want to use the re.VERBOSE flag ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you split the text with '*END', then clean up the resulting pieces. This should be faster than going line by line or using regular expressions. I think it also captures the essence of the task, which is to find things separated by '*END'.

```
raw_parts = data.split('*END')
parts = []
for part in raw_parts:
    part = part.strip()
    if len(part) != 0:
        parts.append(part)

print(parts)
```

In response to your comment about the possibility of other types of data mingled with the numerical blocks, let me suggest this solution using a regular expression. The key idea is to use `re.DOTALL` to make the period match across multiple lines. That may be the behavior you were expecting from `re.MULTILINE`.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(\d.*?)\*END', re.DOTALL)
blocks = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), pattern.findall(data)))
print(blocks)
```

Comment: Same answer than for Jasper and Avinash, potentially the file has other informations that are not consistent with the section specification...

Comment: I understand. I've edited my answer to show another solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
([\d\s]+)(?=\*END)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qZ6sE3/3

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([\d\s]+)(?=\*END)')
test_str = u"1 2 3 4\n 2 5 6 7\n3 8 9 10\n*END\n\n\n1 11 12 13\n2 14 15 16\n3 17 18 19\n*END"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Edit:

For new requiremnt try

```
((?:\s*\d+(?:\s+\d+){4}\s*)*)(?=\s*\*END)
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qZ6sE3/9

Comment: Wow, it perfectly does the trick and thank you for the link ! Very usefull to identify and debug regex !

Comment: @AvinashRaj not really but this is not of primal importance as it will be easy to parse block strings at a second stage. The first goal was to extract block sections.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you,

```
import re
import sys
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()
    file = re.sub(r'(?s)\n\*END$', r'', file)
    print(re.split(r'\n\*END\n+', file))
```

Output:

```
['1 2 3 4\n 2 5 6 7\n3 8 9 10', '1 11  12 13\n2 14 15 16\n3 17 18 19\n']
```